# In search of A/C Condensate Drain Cleaning Trap

Tags: hvac, drain, pipe

Living in south florida, I have to periodically pour some vinegar down my A/C condensate line to keep it from fouling/backing up and causing a mess. The condensate pan tablets don't seem to help or don't last long. As it is I have to unhook a flexible hose every time, which is a bit of a pain. Unfortunately I have a very tight place where I can hook into it. I'm wondering if there exists some sort of cleaning trap I can use that's compact in size. Here's a photo [image]
Right below is the breaker so I can't really block it too much.

Comment: Your drawing looks like a clean out not a trap. Quit using vinegar it is a week acid and will cause your condensate pan to start rusting as vinegar eats the zinc. Get some condensate cleaning tablets, 3-4 of the large ones will make through a entire heating season in a hot humid climate it may take 8-9 about 15$ at a big box store. They keep the gunkies from growing in the pan and the drain clean the last plus is they prevent legionnaires yes it was first found in ac systems.

Comment: As I mentioned I do use tablets in the pan, I put about 6 every 6 months, but it's not enough. The pan is actually plastic, but I don't put the vinegar in the pan, rather down the PVS pipe.

Comment: Quit using vinegar and possibly find the larger tablets if your humidity is wiping out the small ones you are not protected when they are gone even try stacking 2 of the larger ones. Your humidity is higher than my area I have used as few as 6 for an entire season and still had part of one left, I installed a plexiglass cover so I could see it replace when gone.

Comment: You need a proper trap to get correct flow of condensate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an "A/C condensate trap" with easy cleanout doors and it even comes with a cute little brush.  There are also versions with overflow alarms.

I have these on my A/Cs. You can clean the trap with the brush but you ought to clean the whole drain line periodically, and that usually is done with compressed air.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could put a "T" there but be sure the stub is long enough to be above the pan, if not water will run out. Also place a cap, not glued or anything on the stub, otherwise cold air will escape. It is best to design it so the vinegar does not run back into the pan. Then when cleaning you remove the cap, pour in the vinegar and replace the ca. Happy clean drain!

Comment: It's also an elbow though. I don't think I've seen them come like that. If I go with the lower option, I'd like more something like a Y. I'm just not sure how to search for the these parts. Haven't found one that matches at like Home Depot.

Comment: Place the "T" where you 90 down. Use it as a 90 with the other leg sticking up.  -|